# Insert records from another object in section with visualforce

Tags: visualforce, controller-extension

I need insert a section in object registo__c with a lists with records from another object task__c, but just all tasks aggregated to a same project that registo__c

So in registo__c I have a lookup to project__c where have a project_pm__c  lookup field.

And in the task__c object I have a lookup field to project_pm__c

How can write this code. I can show all tasks list with tasks records in registo__c but I can't filter to show just tasks that have the same project_pm__c that registo__c.

In visualforce page I do a extension to code, and show records from tasks__c with map.

Somebody can help me?

Comment: This reads like there is a `project_pm__c` object with a `project__c` child object (and a `task__c` child object) and a `registo__c` grand child object. With that situation you could show all the `task__c` objects related to the `project_pm__c` as a list in the `registo__c` detail page, but you could not have a breakdown to specific `project__c` objects because there is no relationship modelling that. Can you clarify this point?

Comment: echoing Keith -- a schema diagram and example records would help get you the best support here

Comment: Object tasks__c--> have project_pm__c
registo__c -> have lookup to object project__c
Inside the project__c have a lookup field project_pm__c

this to project_pm__c its the same

What I want is in a registo__c show all tasks that project_pm__c have related with that registo__c.

Comment: Object tasks__c--> have project_pm__c
registo__c -> have lookup to object project__c
Inside the project__c have a lookup field project_pm__c

this to project_pm__c its the same

What I want is in a registo__c show all tasks that project_pm__c have related with that registo__c.

So, show in detail page in registo__c, have one section show all tasks that project have.

I don't no if this help, but in registo__c object have a field task.

Comment: Sounds like you will need to build a wrapper class to hold the project and associated tasks based on the PM associated with the project. The issue will be since the task is not specifically related to a project that tasks listed may not relate to the project at all since it is to the PM. If the PM has multiple projects the tasks would be listed under each

Answer (score 0):

A controller something like the one below would return the list of `task__c` objects related to the parent `project_pm__c` of a single `registo__c` object in its detail page.

(There appears to be no relationship between `task__c` and `project__c` in your data model so there is no way to limit the returned `task__c` object to only those related to the `registo__c`'s parent `project__c`.)

```
public with sharing RegisteroController {
    private ApexPages.StandardController sc;
    public RegisteroController(ApexPages.StandardController sc) {
        this.sc = sc;
    }
    public task__c[] tasks {
        get {
            if (tasks == null) {
                registo__c r = [
                        select project__r.project_pm__r.id
                        from registo__c
                        where id = :sc.getId()
                        ];
                Id ppmId = r.project__r.project_pm__r.id;
                tasks = [
                        select Name, ...
                        from task__c
                        where project_pm__c = :ppmId
                        order by ...
                        ];
            }
            return tasks;
        }
        private set;
    }
}
```

The page would look something like this:

```
<apex:page standardController="registo__c" extensions="RegisteroController">
   ...
   <apex:pageBlockSection title="Tasks" columns="1">
       <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!tasks}" var="t">
           <apex:column value="{!t.Name}"/>
           <apex:column value="{!t.???}"/>
           ...
       </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
   ...
</apex:page>
```

To find out more about queries between related objects - you can query many levels up the parent hierarchy and one level down the child hierarchy in a single query -  see e.g. [Relationship Queries](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm).

Comment: Show this error
"List has no rows for assignment to SObject"
"Class.RegisteroController.__sfdc_tasks: line 10, column 1"

Comment: @Lisyy Did you open the page with a URL like /apex/YourPageName?id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx where xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx is a valid registo__c id? This is a convention for a standard controller extension. (You can override the registo__c view action with this page and that URL patter will be automatically used.)

Comment: the error disappeared but the table is empty

Comment: @Lisyy Are you sure there are Task__c objects related to the registo__c object you chose? Check the objects by manually querying them in the developer console.